# How to disable wicket's setRequired for certain cases

Tags: javascript, java, html, user-interface, wicket

I am fairly new to wicket and have just come across setRequired.

I have 5 textfields

```
    final TextField<String> mfnField = new TextField<>("mfn",
                model(criteriaModel, on(RechercheServiceFunctionCriteria.class).getMfn()));
        form.add(mfnField);
        mfnField.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        form.add(new FdsInfoButton("mfn.infoButton", new ResourceModel("mfn.infoButton")));
        form.add(new FormComponentFeedbackPanel("mfnFeedbackPanel", mfnField));

final TextField<String> pbField = new TextField<>("pid",
                model(criteriaModel, on(RechercheServiceFunctionCriteria.class).getPBId()));
        form.add(pbField);
        pbField.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        form.add(new FormComponentFeedbackPanel("pidFeedbackPanel", pbField));

        final TextField<String> gpidField = new TextField<>("gpid",
                model(criteriaModel, on(RechercheServiceFunctionCriteria.class).getGpid()));
        form.add(gpidField);
        gpidField.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        form.add(new FormComponentFeedbackPanel("gpidFeedbackPanel", gpidField));

        final TextField<String> tidField = new TextField<>("tid",
                model(criteriaModel, on(RechercheServiceFunctionCriteria.class).getTransaction_id()));
        form.add(tidField);
        form.add(new FdsInfoButton("tid.infoButton", new ResourceModel("tid.infoButton")));
        form.add(new FormComponentFeedbackPanel("tidFeedbackPanel", tidField));
final TextField<String> ibanField = new TextField<>("iban",
                model(criteriaModel, on(RechercheServiceFunctionCriteria.class).getIban()));
        form.add(ibanField);
        ibanField.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        form.add(new FormComponentFeedbackPanel("ibanFeedbackPanel", ibanField));
```

I have a fromfield and a tofield:

```
final DateTimePicker fromInput = new DateTimePicker("from",
                model(criteriaModel, on(RechercheServiceFunctionCriteria.class).getFromDate()),
                DateTimePicker.START_OF_DAY);
        form.add(fromInput);
        form.add(new FormComponentFeedbackPanel("fromFeedbackPanel", fromInput));

        final DateTimePicker toInput = new DateTimePicker("to",
                model(criteriaModel, on(RechercheServiceFunctionCriteria.class).getToDate()),
                DateTimePicker.END_OF_DAY);
        form.add(toInput);
        form.add(new FormComponentFeedbackPanel("toFeedbackPanel", toInput));
```

Out of the 5 textfields:

- if anything is entered in the 1st four then I will need fromfield and tofield to be entered as well so for this setRequired should be true
- but if there's anything entered into tidField, regardless of the other textfields being empty or filled, setRequired should be false for the frominput and toinput.

My question is how do I set the true and false.

Or is there something else I can use other than setRequired?

Comment: I’ve just [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still need to add further information for your question to become solvable.

Comment: Your question has been closed before we have a chance to answer you. Take a look at IFormValidator class. You need to implement it and list `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` as dependencies, then add it to the form: `myForm.add(new MyFormValidator()`. This way you will have the values of all the dependencies and you can decide whether to pass the validation or to fail it.

Comment: @martin-g I have tried doing it in the IFormValidator as well but it reacts weirdly everytime, sometimes it shows the error messages and other times it doesnot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: 
I had to use isRequired and not setRequired

```
final DateTimePicker fromInput = new DateTimePicker("from",
                model(criteriaModel, on(RechercheServiceFunctionCriteria.class).getFromDate()),
                DateTimePicker.START_OF_DAY) {
            /**
             *
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public boolean isRequired() {
                return Strings.isBlank(tidField.getConvertedInput());
            }

        };
        form.add(fromInput);
        form.add(new FormComponentFeedbackPanel("fromFeedbackPanel", fromInput));

        final DateTimePicker toInput = new DateTimePicker("to",
                model(criteriaModel, on(RechercheServiceFunctionCriteria.class).getToDate()),
                DateTimePicker.END_OF_DAY) {

            /**
                     *
                     */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public boolean isRequired() {
                return Strings.isBlank(tidField.getConvertedInput());
            }
        };
        form.add(toInput);
```